# Integrate custom task into lifecycle of multi project build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a multi-project build containing the two java library modules 'A' and 'B'. 'B' has an dependency to module 'A':

```
dependencies {
  api ':A'
}
```

Now I want to write a custom plugin that provides the custom task 'myGenerator'. 'myGenerator' must run before compiling any classes (task compileJava) in module 'B' but after assembling module 'A' ('myGenerator' will implement a code generator that needs some resources of module 'A').

How shall I configure task 'myGenerator'? If I say

```
compileJava.dependsOn myGenerator
```

and run `gradle assemble` within module 'B', 'myGenerator' still gets executed before assembling module 'A'.

Somehow I have to configure 'myGenerator' to have a dependency to the configuration 'api' of module 'A'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You only expressed one dependency from your sentence:

> 'myGenerator' must run before compiling any classes (task compileJava) in module 'B' but after assembling module 'A'

You need to express the other one:

```
myGenerator.dependsOn project(':A').jar // or the relevant assembly task of your build
```